# How to use a phrase chunker in the StanfordCoreNLP pipeline?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Suppose I have defined the following StanfordCoreNLP pipeline:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("language", "english");
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, depparse");
props.put("depparse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_SD.gz");
props.put("parse.originalDependencies", true);

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline =  new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Now, I would like to use the Stanford chunker as well in the pipeline so I could discover NPs, VPs, ... (I guess with the [Chunk Identifier](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/LabeledChunkIdentifier.html)). Also, I wouldn't want to do lexicalized parsing, just a dependency parse (as specified in the properties). Is this possible? If so, could you provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: I would expect `props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, chunk, ner, parse, dcoref, sentiment");` to work but I've not personally used that, so it may not work.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's part of the pipeline code: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP.java#L440 =(

Comment: Stanford CoreNLP doesn't have a chunker, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Hm...too bad. Thanks for the answers, guys!